# Sinatra app running in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I need to take this Sinatra app and have it run in rails. I get I can place this in the lib folder and set up the routes. But how do I set up the route to accept the parameter?

```
    kClientId = ""
    kClientSecret = ""
    kClientCallbackURL = ""

    set :port, 1234 # The port to bind to.

    post '/swap' do

        # This call takes a single POST parameter, "code", which
        # it combines with your client ID, secret and callback
        # URL to get an OAuth token from the Spotify Auth Service,
        # which it will pass back to the caller in a JSON payload.

        auth_code = params[:code]

        uri = URI.parse("https://ws.spotify.com")
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/oauth/token")
        request.form_data = {
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "client_id" => kClientId,
            "client_secret" => kClientSecret,
            "redirect_uri" => kClientCallbackURL,
            "code" => auth_code
        }

        response = http.request(request)

        status response.code.to_i
        return response.body

    end
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate (including identical code) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445318/turning-a-sinatra-app-into-a-rails-controller

Answer (score 0):

[Mount Sinatra app inside a rails app and sharing layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856524/mount-sinatra-app-inside-a-rails-app-and-sharing-layout)

Basically you can mount your app and all the routes in your Sinatra App will be prefixed by the route under which you mounted it. Params will be passed as usual.