# Sinatra app in Rails 4.1 config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, puma

I want to fake an API with a little Sinatra app, following [this method](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/faking-apis-in-development-and-staging). Meaning I have a Rails app, and in the spec/support folder, a very simple Sinatra app:

```
module FakePrograms
  class Application < Sinatra::Base
    get "/API/V1/programs" do
      {
        programs: [
          ...
        ]
      }.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

Part of the goal is to launch this app locally, so I can work on my Rails app with a fake API. Problem: when I do `ruby spec/support/fake_programs.rb`, the app can't boot, and I get a

```
config/puma.rb:14:in `block in _load_from':
uninitialized constant
#<Class:#<Puma::DSL:0x007fac0b0e0380>>::ActiveRecord (NameError)
```

Looks like Sinatra is booting using my Rails configuration. I don't need ActiveRecord nor Puma for my fake API.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856524/mount-sinatra-app-inside-a-rails-app-and-sharing-layout) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760270/how-to-make-a-sinatra-app-run-in-rails-4), but theese are in different context, because they need their Sinatra app to share routes with the Rails app.

Content of config/puma.rb:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I was looking at the config.ru file, but @max is right, it's not correlated.

Comment: not seeing why the `config.ru` is read if you are calling the ruby file directly with `ruby spec/support/fake_programs.rb`. Is this really what's happening? Maybe show your `config.ru` and `config/puma.rb` as well.

Comment: You're right, question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Puma README](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/v3.6.0/README.md#configuration-file) says:

> By default, if no configuration file is specified, Puma will look for a configuration file at config/puma.rb.

Which is why your app is using this config file.

It goes on to say:

> If you want to prevent Puma from looking for a configuration file in those locations, provide a dash as the argument to the `-C` (or `--config`) flag:
>
> ```
> $ puma -C "-"
> ```

Since Puma can handle Sinatra apps directly, you could start your app like this:

```
$ puma -c "-" spec/support/fake_programs.rb
```

If you want to start your app using `ruby` with Puma as the built in server (as you are doing now), I think adding this to your Sinatra app should work (neither Sinatra’s `:server_settings` or Puma’s `:config_files` are very well documented):

```
set :server, 'puma'
set :server_settings, {:config_files => "-"}
```